# how to make join on this in mogodb

Tags: mongodb

```
db.getCollection('users').find({ roles: { $gt: [] },clientId:'59395447dbc362740459af5f'})


db.getCollection('users').find({clientId: '59395447dbc362740459af5f', '$and': [ { state: 'Tennessee' },{region:'South'}]});
```

i am having set of users in that i am having the column called roles i need to get all the user who has having roles.
remaining user who have not any roles applied should apply filter using the second query.
i need both records in same query.
Is this possible.

Comment: you should add some description what is the problem and what do you want?

Comment: You probably mean [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). But the question is unclear.

Comment: roles: { $gt: [] } which get all the users who have roles field non empty

Comment: @KarthikeyanKanagaraj: yes, I read about it. Be careful, though. It may return empty result set if a wrong index is selected.

Answer (score 0):

db.getCollection('users').find({clientId: '59395447dbc362740459af5f',   "$or":[{"roles: { $gt: [] } },{ '$and':[ { state: 'Alabama' },{ region: 'South' }] }]});